# Как из вложенного массива, делать обыкновенный?

Tags: php

Есть такой вложенный массив:

```
$arr = [
   [1], [2], [3]
];
```

Как из него сделать обыкновенный массив? Вот такой:

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3];
```

Comment: если маленький то `array_merge(...$arr)`

Answer (score 0):

```php
$new_arr = [];
foreach ($arr as $item_arr) {
    $new_arr[] = $item_arr[0];
}
```